# CSS background with some borders

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with adding background to div element.

```
<div class="bg-box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolorem</p>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppssr6nL/)

It's not too much, but what I want to have is:

[image: weird bg]

Any idea how can I add this?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry about poor explanation. What I want and need is this to be done with css only, so no image in background. Is it possible? This is just example of the width and height, so I need it to be responsive because it will be used in site background...

Comment: [**check this website**](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/)

Comment: And what "*troubles*" are you having, exactly? Where did you get stuck? What don't you understand? Is that an image, or is it CSS gradient? What help, exactly, do you need?

Comment: [**easy version of the same website**](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify-generator/)

Comment: Doing this with pure css would be extremely annoying and cumbersome.  If you're trying to draw this out and not use an image, I would recommend studying up on canvas html5.

Comment: Please check my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SVG, when embedded it works just like CSS, inline and no "image" to load, it scales and is an excellent way to create patterns like triangles.

Here is a sample with 2 triangles you can use as a start.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }
.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00cfaf;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256'%3E %3Cpolygon points='200,10 250,190 160,210' style='fill:red;stroke-width:0' /%3E %3Cpolygon points='100,50 170,20 160,210' style='fill:yellow;stroke-width:0' /%3E %3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

HTML5 Canvas, though this need script which SVG doesn't.

```js
function init() 
{ 
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 if(canvas.getContext)
 {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
  ctx.fillStyle="#0FF";
  ctx.beginPath();  
  ctx.moveTo(10,10);
  ctx.lineTo(150,10);
  ctx.lineTo(200,110);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
      
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0";
  ctx.beginPath();  
  ctx.moveTo(50,50);
  ctx.lineTo(10,100);
  ctx.lineTo(80,110);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
 }
 }
  
onload=init;
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }

.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00cfaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. I will use this and hopefully achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the background image. Save the image to your local directory and then do something like this

```
div {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Apologies I don't think that's possible with pure css

Answer (score 0):

To use this image as a background add a css rule for either all divs or your bg-box.

```
.bg-box {
  background-image: url("imageFile.jpg");
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

This will make your picture the background of the div.